# PyDev Undefined variable from import error

Tags: python, django, pydev, virtualenv

I'm using virtualenv for Django project. From command line I can import modules hashlib and zipfile. But PyDev is reporting unresolved import for those two. (os, sys and email are working).

When I copy zipfile.py and zipfile.pyc (and same for hashlib) to virtualenv lib's folder I can import modules, but I get errors that md5 variable isn't defined in hashlib and so on. Again, I can call md5 method within virtualenv in command line...

What Can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis -> Undefined -> Undefined Variable From Import -> Ignore

Then try to close and reopen eclipse again, which worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by removing / re-adding the PyDev Interpreter.  I've also seen instances where, on my initial launch of Eclipse the PyDev plugin will fail to load some of my modules (most commonly the wx module) and give me a raft of unresolved import errors.  Restarting Eclipse (from the file menu, not closing and reopening) seems to cause it to reload in some way that makes it properly recognize the previously missing modules.  HTH.

Comment: Unfortunately isn't helping. I don't have any other python libs in path but I can still run this script from PyDev as "Python Run" program...:/

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bug which is described here:
[Pydev for Eclipse: Detail: 3132412 - hashlib.md5() - "Undefined variable from import: md5"](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3132412&group_id=85796&atid=577329)

So it's ok to use #@UndefinedVariable while code is working.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on your module name >> Py Dev >> Remove Error Markers
All my red cross false errors from editors vanished!