# Python and thread - Undefined variable from import: start_new_thread

Tags: python, multithreading, import

While trying to use `thread` in Python , with the following code

```
import select, sys, time, thread

TIMEOUT = 30

def listenthread(server,result):

# some code 
#
#

def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv[1:]
    server = Server()            
    clientaddrs = []
    # listen to clients in new thread
    thread.start_new_thread(listenthread, (server,clientaddrs)) # that line produces a problem
```

I get `Undefined variable from import: start_new_thread` when I reach the line :

```
 thread.start_new_thread(listenthread, (server,clientaddrs))
```

What might be the problem ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common PyDev bug. I see nothing wrong with your code, PyDev is simply alerting you to a non-existent error.

See the answers listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521258/pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-error).